# How do I create a web application using Core Python without a framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build an web application using python as a backend so, as I did not learned any of the web frameworks that are available for python I want to know is there any way to create backend for an app without frameworks.

Comment: It's *much* simpler to simply learn a framework like Django or Flask than to attempt to make one yourself using the standard library tools like `urllib` - thousands of hours have been put into making those tools so that you don't have to figure everything out from scratch and reinvent the wheel. Is there a particular reason you're averse to using frameworks other than "not wanting to learn them"?

Comment: Yes, I want to be strong in basics too...

Comment: You're probably better off reading the source code for existing frameworks before trying to write your own (and don't write your own. big waste of time)

Comment: Ya sure thankyou for your suggestion @m

Comment: I guest your request is about a learning purpose. Yes, you can code your backend in  purely python without using a framework. **How to do it ?** You have to check it through Python documentation or a search engine...

Comment: also i want to implement one application and want to store various details from frontend to the back end using python without framework I am asking is it possible?? @codrelphi

Comment: YES, it is possible. You can achieve your goal. Now, you need to have a basic knowledge of the frontend tols (html, css and perhaps javascript if you want). In the backend, you will use python and surely a database (mariadb, mysql or sqlite should be nice). **How to use python in the backend to build a web app?** You have to check it.

Comment: But, like @GreenCloakGuy said, It is better in your case to learn and understand the internal coren of a micro-framework like **Flask** before. So you can understand more how things works. And for learning purpose, you can build your own micro-framework...

Comment: Yes I had checked it as you said i.e How to use python in the backend to build a web app? and the answers are coming as with frameworks like django,flask etc If you know any of the sources of saying without frameworks please share here @codrelphi

Comment: Here are some links: https://realpython.com/python-web-applications/, https://www.fullstackpython.com/web-development.html, Some frameworks: https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/web/,

Answer (score 1):

While there is a discussion in the comments about the utility of frameworks, I am trying to answer the question at its face value.

#### WSGI

Python frameworks like Flask and Django both at the end are WSGI applications. WSGI (Web Service Gateway Interface) is a PEP specification which defines how the server and client must communicate. If I were to start from scratch, I would probably start with learning about WSGI and even try implementing a little ping-pong server with it. The read the docs page here https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/learn.html lists a number of pages to learn about it.

#### Werkzeug

Once the WSGI specs are understood then one can attempt building a simple library that will wrap the core concepts into reusable functions and modules for easily writing an application. Here Werkzeug can be a good guide to make one understand the different aspects. https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/werkzeug/

#### Your own application

Based on the understanding of the WSGI spec and the Werkzueg library you can go on to write your applications either from scratch, or write a library like werkzueg yourself and then use it to write an application.

Finally reimplement the same app in Flask or Django to see what frameworks offer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something small for internal use you can use
https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html